# AngularJS equivalent of a next element toggle

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

I have a list of "cards" that have two parts. By default I only show the first part.

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cards">
    <div ng-click="displayEditView(card)">{{card.title}}</div>

    <div ng-show="card.displayEditView">
         <input type="text" ng-model="card.title">
    </div>
</div>
```

displayEditView sets card.displayEditView to true (or false if already true).

But I implemented a setInterval that reloads $scope.cards. Of course when that happens the card.displayEditView doesn't exist anymore so the view gets hidden again.

Any idea how I could keep the state of the ng-show the same even when the $scope.cards reloads ?

Comment: Could you provide a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of your code or provide the controller you are using? (specifically interested in that set interval / how you're updating cards)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GbLg1Zk8ZN3Or2Vc79Aa?p=catalogue

Comment: You should manually check if card is new or already exists in cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of the `cards` list everytime you fetch new data, so the card you are saving a view for doesn't exist anymore.

You need to maintain your current list and append or remove cards if you want it to update live.

Pseudo-code example:

```
getCards().then(function(cards) {
  forEach(card in cards) {
    if ($scope.cards.indexOf(card) < 0) {
      // If something in the new list doesn't exist in the existing list, append it.
      // This way you don't overwrite the existing array.
      $scope.cards.push(card);
    }
  }
});
```